# PSQL query select with multiple grouping

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

Please help to create correct select query for postgresql.
I have a table with next data:

| srv | table_name | heartbeat |
| --- | --- | --- |
| server1 | table1 | 10 |
| server1 | table2 | 7 |
| server2 | table1 | 13 |
| server2 | table2 | 23 |
| server3 | table1 | 3 |
| server3 | table2 | 15 |

I try to create select query that will turn back next result:

| table_name | server1 | server2 | server3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| table1 | 10 | 13 | 3 |
| table2 | 7 | 23 | 15 |

Tables names always static (about 20 tables names). But servers names can be changed any time: added or deleted.

Comment: looks like you need PIVOT if I understand you correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using the conditional aggreagtion :

```
select table_name,
       max(case when srv = 'server1' then heartbeat end) as server1,
       max(case when srv = 'server2' then heartbeat end) as server2,
       max(case when srv = 'server3' then heartbeat end) as server3
from mytable
group by table_name
```

Result :

| table_name | server1 | server2 | server3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| table1 | 10 | 13 | 3 |
| table2 | 7 | 23 | 15 |

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/v5mMs01A)

Comment: *servers names can be changed any time: added or deleted.*... this probably requires dynamic SQL instead.

Comment: Thnx. It works.
But is it possible to put servers names to some kind foreach block to use them without knowing how many servers in table?